# Selenium The browser appears to have exited before we could connect

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I tried to make a bot which looks up if the Bob Marley TShirt from Ajax Amsterdamn is available.

https://www.adidas.ch/de/ajax-3-jsy/GT9559.html <- there is the link

I was able to get it running (also added an telegram bot to report the succses:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

token="" # expunged for obvious reasons
chat="" # expunged for obvious reasons
message="Available"
fireFoxOptions = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
fireFoxOptions.set_headless()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=fireFoxOptions)
browser.get("https://www.adidas.ch/de/ajax-3-jsy/GT9559.html")
if ("Dieses Produkt ist leider ausverkauft." not in browser.page_source):
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + chat + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + message  
    response = requests.get(send_text)
    print(response.json())
browser.close()
```

Working on:

- selenium 3.141.0
- python 3
- Firefox 91.0.2
- geckodriver 0.29.1
- OS: Manjaro Linux

So after that I tried to deploy it on my Debian 10 Server but here is where the struggle began. I had to install Firefox 78.14.0esr and according to the github release page of the Geckodriver version 0.27.0 of it. Selenium stayed the same with 3.141.0. From what I know and what I researched the versions should be alright but when executed throw this nervewrecking error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ajax.py", line 18, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options) #, capabilities=cap, executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")
  File "/home/webadmin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/webadmin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/webadmin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/webadmin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/webadmin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

I searched the error up and apparently you have to define the binary paths and the capability "marionette" now I did this and now the code looks like this (including some debugging stuff):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

#token="1995953311:AAH-D7S-MISkCa0yQxUc84Gf978fz0vtoqY"
#chat="1917512203"
message="just a test"

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = False
binary = "/usr/bin/firefox"
options.binary = binary
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, capabilities=cap, executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")

browser.get("https://www.adidas.ch/de/ajax-3-jsy/GT9559.html")
if ("Dieses Produkt ist leider ausverkauft." not in browser.page_source):
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + chat + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + message  
    response = requests.get(send_text)
    print(response.json())
else:
    print("succ")
browser.close()
```

But now I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ajax.py", line 18, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, capabilities=cap, executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")
  File "/home/webadmin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 191, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "/home/webadmin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/webadmin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 73, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/webadmin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 104, in _wait_until_connectable
    "The browser appears to have exited "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Also changing the `cap["marionette"] = False` to `True` just gives me the older error message.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reverted all the changes, made an Docker container and put that on the server.